# No component factory found Error in ionic2 rc0

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-components

i am trying to beta11 to rc0 in ionic2.

one of my page has custom tag as peg the [changelogs](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) i was trying to update my custom tag and and the page as per the point 7 explained

> Import and add each of your custom components and pipes to the declarations array in src/app/app.module.ts.

i have moved my componentTags.ts file to src and take a look at my `@NgModel`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    HomePage,
    AboutUsPage,
    PrivacyPolicyPage,
    TermsOfUsePage,
    ProductSubCategoryPage,
    CategoryProductDetailsPage,
    CategoryProductDetailsInfoPage,

    //custom tags
    QuantityComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    HomePage,
    AboutUsPage,
    PrivacyPolicyPage,
    TermsOfUsePage,
    ProductSubCategoryPage,
    CategoryProductDetailsPage,
    CategoryProductDetailsInfoPage,

    QuantityComponent
  ],
  //directives: [QuantityComponent],
  providers: [
    Products,
    Users,
    Configurator,
    Rest
  ]
```

so here is my custom component file called quantityTag.ts file

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    
    styles: [`

        .quantity-input {
            display:flex; align-items:center;
        }
        .quantity-input .input-width {
            width:50px;
            border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
            padding-top: 5px;
            
        }
        
        ion-icon{
            margin-left:0px;
            height:20px;
            padding-top: 3px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            color:#64c8dc;
            
        }
        button{
            background-color:SteelBlue;
        margin-left: 0px;
        }
    `],
    
    template: `
        <span class="quantity-input" style="">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="counterValue" class="input-width"/> 
            <button small (click)="submit($event)"><ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon></button>
        </span>
    `
})

export class QuantityComponent {
    
    @Input() counterValue = 0;

    @Input() cookie = null;

    @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();

    submit(evt){
        this.counterChange.emit({
          value: this.counterValue,
          cookie: this.cookie
        });
    }



}
```

i am having a page called shopingcart.ts in that i need this custom tag but i am getting error as below

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - inline template:18:27 caused by: No component factory found for ShopingcartPage
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No component factory found for ShopingcartPage

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try add your page in @NgModules

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/loginpage/login-page'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11030